# Configure textarea tooltip with highlighter.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

I'm trying to use [highlighter.js](https://github.com/huffpostlabs/highlighter.js) inside a `textarea`. I've modified [their example](http://huffpostlabs.github.io/highlighter.js/) and replaced the `p` with a `textarea` wrapped by a `pre` (for bidi settings).

```
    <div class="article" style="width: 80%; height: 80%;">
        <pre style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">Highlight some body text! 
                This is a jQuery plugin that allows you to display a pop-up tooltip when a user highlights text. This can be useful in a variety
                of situations, and there didn't seem to be a good open source solution before this.
                on how to implement this on your website. It's very easy!
            </textarea>
        </pre>
    </div>
```

When I a highlight a word the tooltip pops at the wrong location, the bottom-left corner of the `textarea`, regardless of the location of the word. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This worked in Firefox and Chrome for me. What browser are you using. It snapped to the last word in the highlighted area. If I highlight one word it snapped right to that word. Hope this helps.

Comment: Chromium, in FF I don't see any tooltip. Weird.